I cannot install ANYTHING from discover or do apt upgrades (Ubuntu Studio 24.04)
**

SOLVED link: https://askubuntu.com/a/17297/1857701

**
whenever I install anything in discover it just shows error couldn't be installed. In the terminal I do sudo apt update and the sudo apt upgrade, I get this
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avldrums.lv2 : Depends: avldrums.lv2-data (= 5:0.4.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

after some other stuff and typing Y after sudo apt --fix-broken install gives this
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 417072 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../avldrums.lv2-data_5%3a0.4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking avldrums.lv2-data (5:0.4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/avldrums.lv2-data_5%3a0.4.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/lv2/avldrums.lv2/Black_Pearl_4_LV2.sf2', which is also in package avldrums.lv2-soundfont 0.7.2-1build2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/avldrums.lv2-data_5%3a0.4.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

someone pls help

I'm a complete  newbie I don't understand anything. The only other thing I did was probably tried installing some flatpak packages such as chrome and ppsspp. I thinnk it broke after this :(

Try executing sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/avldrums.lv2-data_5%3a0.4.1_all.deb Then you can execute sudo apt -f install to fix broken installtions/dependencies.
